# Problem with mat table server side pagination and filtering data

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have this code which is the standard https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples#table-http 
I have a problem with filtering though, whenever I filter the data. The data returned from the api is at a different endPoint and is not paginated. When I assign that data to the `MatTableDataSource`  if the user click on the next arrow on the table, the normal api gets called again, which is the not what I need. I want it to only fetch data on next arrow only if there's no filtered data. So far I have tried using `iif` to check the condition but I can't seem to get it to work.

```
 ngAfterViewInit() {
    merge(this.itemPagi.page)
      .pipe(
        startWith({}),
        switchMap(() => {
          this.showSpinner = true;
          return this.storeService
            .listItems(this.itemPagi.pageIndex)
            .pipe(catchError(() => of(null)));
        }),
        map((data) => {
          this.showSpinner = false;
          if (data === null) {
            return [];
          }
          this.paginatorData = data;
          this.resultsLength = data.count;
          return data.results;
        })
      )
      .subscribe((data) => (this.itemDs = new MatTableDataSource(data)));
  }
```

I have this code which is the standard https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples#table-http
I have a problem with filtering though, whenever I filter the data returned from the api is not paginated, when I assign that data to the MatTableDataSource  if the user click on the next arrow on the table, the pagination api gets called again, which is the not what I need. I want it to only fetch data if there's no filtered data. So far I have tried using iif to check the condition but I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator; try to reset the data source of paginator

Comment: same behavior @KumailHussain

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-pagination-server-side-pagination-waxghf
can you see this example

Comment: or you can share the complete picture of code, its not clear from you post whats happening